# How do I read a binary file via HTTP in node?

Tags: node.js, http

I have an image on a web server (http://example.com/img.jpg). I open that image in a browser and save it to disk.

If I open the file in node via the '`fs`' module (`fs.readFileSync`), I get a Buffer that begins with 0xff, which is what I would expect.

I'd like to be able to get the same result directly from an HTTP request. I'm using the 'request' module to make the request.

```
request('http://example.com/img.jpg',function(error, response, body){
  //code here
});
```

I can't figure out how to turn the response or body into an equivalent Buffer from what I'm getting from the FileSystem. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a `Buffer` by setting the [`encoding`](https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback) to `null`:

```
request('http://example.com/img.jpg', { encoding: null }, function(error, response, body){
  console.log(Buffer.isBuffer(body)); // true
});
```

`request` treats any other value [as an argument](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/d734337ad821894428fa0eabf65d0e88697dd4a2/main.js#L650-L654) for [`buffer.toString()`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end), which defaults `undefined` to `"utf8"`.